# JIRA : Fetching Issues with limit not compatible with 3.13.2 version

Tags: java, arrays, jira

I am trying to fetch issues from a filter from remote JIRA using JIRA SOAP API. The filter returns around 1800 issues which can increase in future. Since, it is giving a Out Of Heap Memory Exception I decided to use `getIssuesFromFilterWithLimit()` method according to [javadoc](http://docs.atlassian.com/rpc-jira-plugin/4.4/com/atlassian/jira/rpc/soap/JiraSoapService.html) which gives this exception

```
No such operation 'getIssuesFromFilterWithLimit'
at org.apache.axis.message.SOAPFaultBuilder.createFault(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:222)
at org.apache.axis.message.SOAPFaultBuilder.endElement(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:129)
at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.endElement(DeserializationContext.java:1087)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.parse(DeserializationContext.java:227)
at org.apache.axis.SOAPPart.getAsSOAPEnvelope(SOAPPart.java:696)
at org.apache.axis.Message.getSOAPEnvelope(Message.java:435)
at org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.MustUnderstandChecker.invoke(MustUnderstandChecker.java:62)
at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:206)
at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)
at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)
at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
at org.swift.common.soap.jira.JirasoapserviceV2SoapBindingStub.getIssuesFromFilterWithLimit(JirasoapserviceV2SoapBindingStub.java:8337)
at ExampleClient.main(ExampleClient.java:50)
```

When I searched on google, I found a forum saying that the method is only compatible with JIRA 3.13.3 + versions and my remote JIRA version is 3.13.2

Is there any way to limit the number of entries  in the returning array?